# How to Display All The RecordStore available in Device

Tags: java-me, rms, recordstore

I am Developing a `Java ME` Application. Here I want to list all the `RecordStore` available. How can I get the names of all the `RecordStore` exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called `listRecordStores` , it returns String Array of the available RMS.

For e.g.

```
RecordStore rs = new RecordStore();

rs.listRecordStores() will return the Array of available RMS.
```